# Get initial value on nested serializer with many=True

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

```
class SomeSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ("currency", "amount")
        model = SomeModel
    def get_amount(self, value):
        if getattr(self, "initial_data", None):
            currency = self.initial_data.get("currency")  # for a case when serializer used directly
        else:
            currency = self.root.initial_data[self.source]["currency"]  # for a case when serializer is nested
        # do some stuff 
        return amount
```

My serializers works fine, bith when is's used directly or as nested serializer. Here is serializer that uses previous one as nested:

```
class OperationSerializer(Serializer):
    ...
    operation = SomeSerializer()
```

Everything works fine until I try to use OperationSerializer with many=True. In this case I cannot get initial value of currency, because I need to specify an index for the root element which is not known for me.

Comment: getting any errors?

Comment: currency = self.root.initial_data[self.source]["cryptocurrency"]  
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: @Sumithran if many=True than root is not an object anymore, it's a list

Comment: please post relevant codes

Comment: @Sumithran It is quite relevant, just with changed naming